# Which vtable does the object of subtype use in c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism, virtual, vtable

when I want to execute this line of code, it doesn't compile

```
    baseArray[1]->function5();
```

But in vtable of Derived 3, function5 should points to function5 in Derived1. so I think it should output Derived1::function5(). But it seems to find function5() in the Base class

I just wondering that Derived3 inherited from Derived1, why it still check if the called function exists in Base class?

Please refer to the following code.
Thank you for your help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
  virtual void function1();
  virtual void function2();
  virtual void function3() = 0;
  void function4();
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
public:
  void function1();
  virtual void function5();
  void function6();
};

class Derived2 : public Base {
public:
  void function2();
  void function3();
  void function4();
  void function5();
};

class Derived3 : public Derived1 {
public:
  void function3();
};

void Base::function1(){
  cout << "Base::function1()" << endl;
}

void Base::function2(){
  cout << "Base::function2()" << endl;
}

void Base::function4(){
  cout << "Base::function4()" << endl;
}

void Derived1::function1(){
  cout << "Derived1::function1()" << endl;
}

void Derived1::function5(){
  cout << "Derived1::function5()" << endl;
}

void Derived1::function6(){
  cout << "Derived1::function6()" << endl;
}

void Derived2::function2(){
  cout << "Derived2::function2()" << endl;
}

void Derived2::function3(){
  cout << "Derived2::function3()" << endl;
}

void Derived2::function4(){
  cout << "Derived2::function4()" << endl;
}

void Derived2::function5(){
  cout << "Derived2::function5()" << endl;
}

void Derived3::function3(){
  cout << "Derived3::function3()" << endl;
}

int main(){
  Base *baseArray[] = { new Derived2, new Derived3 };
  baseArray[1]->function5(); //why the code doesn't compile when I call function5() here? 
                             //in vtable of Derived 3, function5 should points to function5 in Derived1
                             //so I think it should output Derived1::function5()

  dynamic_cast<Derived3*>(baseArray[1])->function5();
  
  baseArray[1]->function6(); //same question, why it doesn't call function6 in Derived1?
                             //which vtable does baseArray[1] use?

  dynamic_cast<Derived3*>(baseArray[1])->function6();
}
```

Comment: the vtable is an implementation detail. If there was no vtable, nothing would change. Please include the compiler error in the question

Comment: `Base` has no `function5`.

Comment: I believe a much more minimal code example (stripping off a bunch of distractions) is `class Base { public: virtual void fun1() {} };
class Derived : public Base { public: virtual void fun5() {} };

int main()
{
    Base * ptr = new Derived;
    ptr->fun5();
}
`

Comment: `function5` being virtual or not is irrelevant. The error would be the same if `function5` was *not* virtual because, either way, there is no `function5` in `Base`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ is a statically typed language. That means references to types, members, variables, etc have to be known at compile-time.

The reason why `baseArray[1]->function5();` and `baseArray[1]->function6();` do not compile is because `baseArray[1]` is declared as a `Base*` but `function5()` and `function6()` are not members of `Base`. Simple as that.  This has nothing to do with vtables.  That is just an *implementation detail* of how compilers may choose to implement the dispatching of virtual method calls at runtime, but this is not required by the C++ standard.

The compiler doesn’t know that the `Base*` pointer is actually pointing at a `Derived3` object.  That fact is not determined until runtime.  This is a key feature of polymorphism.

To call `function5()` and `function6()` correctly, you will need to type-cast the `Base*` pointer to a derived type that has the member you want to access, as you have already discovered. Note that `dynamic_cast` on a pointer will return `nullptr` if the cast fails, which you are not checking for, eg:

```cpp
// Derived1 and Derived2 are not related, but each has its own function5()...
if (Derived1 *d1 = dynamic_cast<Derived1*>(baseArray[index]))
    d1->function5();
else if (Derived2 *d2 = dynamic_cast<Derived2*>(baseArray[index]))
    d2->function5();
```

On the other hand, if you know the exact and correct type up front (as in your example), you can use `static_cast` instead, eg:

```cpp
static_cast<Derived1*>(baseArray[index])->function5();
```